# Multiple CheckedListBox and database connections

Tags: c#, .net

I'm loading a table from a database into a `CheckedListBox`, and now I need to check which items are checked any time the user changes the check status of an item in the first `CheckedListBox`, and then add the corresponding parts of another table from my database to the second `CheckedListBox`.

So for example, I have `chlbMeal` and `chlbFood`. Inside the `chlbMeal` there are "Breakfast", "Dinner" and "Lunch". Now when the user selects any of these, I want the corresponding food options to show up in the `chlbFood` - for example, if "Breakfast" is checked, inside `chlbFood` we have "Fried eggs", "Eggs and Bacon", etc.

My project is somewhat different but that's the main the idea I want to achieve in this part of it.  Here is my code:

```
private void chlbRadovi_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (chlbRadovi.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            int[] niz = new int[chlbRadovi.CheckedIndices.Count];
            chlbRadovi.CheckedIndices.CopyTo(niz, 0);
            foreach (int x in niz)
            {
                this.tipradovaTableAdapter1.Fill(this.ignaDataSet1.tipradova);
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Konekcija.con);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select IDTR, Naziv from tipradova where IDRad in @IDRad", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDRad", chlbRadovi.ValueMember[x]);
                SqlDataReader reader;

                chlbTipoviRadova.DataSource = ignaDataSet1.tipradova;
                chlbTipoviRadova.DisplayMember = "Naziv";
                chlbTipoviRadova.ValueMember = "IDTR";

                con.Open();
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            chlbTipoviRadova.DataSource = null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here we go. First, bind data to your first `CheckedListbox`:

```
private string connectionString = "Your connection string";

private void cbListFirst_SetDataSource()
{
    // Using block will automatically close connection when it's not used anymore
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT Id, Name
                            FROM dbo.FoodTypes";

        try
        {
            con.Open();

            var foodTypes = new List<FoodType>();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // Fill items for first CheckedListBox DataSource
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    foodTypes.Add(new FoodType()
                    {
                        Id = (int)reader["Id"],
                        Name = reader["Name"] as string
                    });
                }
            }

            // Set first CheckedListBox DataSource
            cbListFirst.DataSource = foodTypes;
            cbListFirst.DisplayMember = "Name";
            cbListFirst.ValueMember = "Id";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Clear DataSource and handle error (should be improved)
            cbListFirst.DataSource = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Error", ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

After you've done that, you should have *ParentIds* encapsulated inside your *FoodType* objects inside `DataSource` of your first `CheckedListbox`. Now, you shouldn't use `SelectedIndexChanged` event, but `ItemCheck` event instead. So every time user checks or unchecks one of the items event will be triggered. Only problem you have now is that inside this event, new *CheckValue* of clicked item is not yet applied, but it can be handled easy since we have information about new and old value inside `EventArgs`. Check this out:

```
private void cbListFirst_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    // Clear second CheckedListbox DataSource
    cbListSecond.DataSource = null;

    var ingridients = new List<Ingridient>();
    foreach (var item in cbListFirst.CheckedItems)
    {
        // If item was previously checked, we want to skip it because it's new value is
        // unchecked and we shouldn't be adding it's child items to second CheckedListbox
        if (cbListFirst.Items.IndexOf(item) != e.Index)
        {
            var foodType = (FoodType)item;
            ingridients.AddRange(GetIngridientsForFoodType(foodType.Id));
        }
    }

    // If item was previously unchecked, it's child items won't be caught in previous loop
    // so we want to explicitly include them inside this if-block if new value is checked
    if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        var foodType = (FoodType)cbListFirst.Items[e.Index];
        ingridients.AddRange(GetIngridientsForFoodType(foodType.Id));
    }

    // Finally, bind new DataSource
    cbListSecond.DataSource = ingridients;
    cbListSecond.DisplayMember = "Name";
    cbListSecond.ValueMember = "Id";
}

// This method returns list of Ingridients for single FoodType
private List<Ingridient> GetIngridientsForFoodType(int foodTypeId)
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT Id, Name
                            FROM dbo.Ingridients
                            WHERE FoodTypeId = @FoodTypeId";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FoodTypeId", foodTypeId);

        try
        {
            con.Open();

            var ingridients = new List<Ingridient>();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    ingridients.Add(new Ingridient()
                    {
                        Id = (int)reader["Id"],
                        Name = reader["Name"] as string
                    });
                }
            }

            return ingridients;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle error (should be improved) and return null
            MessageBox.Show("Error", ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now your second `CheckedListbox` should be filled with child values of items from first `CheckedListbox`.

Comment: Thanks! And how would you go through the values of the checked items in the checkedlistbox?

Comment: You have that part inside ItemCheck event. foreach(var item in cbListFirst.CheckedItems) { } You need to cast item object to the type of your dataSource value.